# PSU wont start after the power shut off and Loud noise

Tags: power-supply

I have recently just purchased the new PC. I ordered the Corsair TM650 80+Gold. Yesterday night there was a big loud firecracker noise and everything was shut off ( this happened last time when my modem was connected to the outlet and all the power was running in the house but TP-link modem works fine even after the bang noise). After the loud noise, the PSU is unresponsive. Should I try changing the wire of the PSU?

Comment: It sounds like an electrolytic cap in your PSU exploded.   https://www.instructables.com/id/Why-Capacitors-Explodes-/ This is a fairly common failure mode for power supply equipment.   Some devices can sometimes limp along with a damaged cap, which is not great, but could explain why your other equipment still works - or at least kind-of works.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your post, it sounds like you have electrical issues in your home.  That is out of scope for this forum.  That being said, it would appear you have blown your power supply unit and it will need to be replaced.  Additionally, any electronics that you value should be run off of surge protectors.